# Reading Two Quadrature Encoder using a single Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due, atmel-studio, rotary-encoder

I am working on an autonomous robot in my summer vacations. I am currently working on running the motors of my robot in a closed loop. In order to do so, I have to interface **two Quadrature encoders** of the motors with the Arduino Due that I have. My motor encoder have **3200 Edges per Revolution**. I have read the Atmel SAM3x8E datasheet and have successfully tested one encoder in Arduino IDE. It appears that TIOA0 and TIOBO are used to read PHA and PHB of of one Encoder which correspond to Pin 2 and 13 of Arduino Due. I am not using Index pin (TIOB1).

[image]

It seems that I can only interface 1 quadrature .Is their any way I can use Quadrature decoder to read 2 encoders instead of one. As I have stated earlier I am not using the index pin. So, maybe there might be a way to decode to encoders using the three available pins as shown in the above diagram. I don't want to use Interrupts to do this job.

Here's is the link of SAM3x Manual:
http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf

Link of Motor that i am using:
www.pololu.com/product/2824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Quadrature Decoder QDEC for SAM3/4 Devices_ApplicationNote_AT11483](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42706-Quadrature-Decoder-QDEC-for-SAM3-4-Devices_ApplicationNote_AT11483.pdf) and referenced excel sheet with [Device to No of QDEC channels](http://atmel.force.com/support/servlet/fileField?id=0BEG0000000HRvP) it seems to have two of them. However in DUE almost none of interesting devices are wired to headers completely (Extmem, SD interface,...)

However TIOA6 and TIOB6 should be on pins 5 and 4

Pin configuration should be something like this:

```
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC25B_TIOA6, PIO_DEFAULT);
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC26B_TIOB6, PIO_DEFAULT);
```

And TC0 is pretty much same as TC2, so just copy&paste and change TC0 to TC2

Full config:

```
  REG_PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER0_PID27 | PMC_PCER0_PID28 | PMC_PCER0_PID29; 
  REG_PMC_PCER1 = PMC_PCER1_PID33 | PMC_PCER1_PID34 | PMC_PCER1_PID35;

  PIO_Configure(PIOB, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PB25B_TIOA0, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 2
  PIO_Configure(PIOB, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PB27B_TIOB0, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 13

  REG_TC0_CMR2  = TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4 | TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_ACPC_TOGGLE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC;
  REG_TC0_RC2   = F_CPU / 128 / 1;
  REG_TC0_CMR0  = TC_CMR_ABETRG | TC_CMR_LDRA_EDGE | TC_CMR_LDRB_EDGE | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_EDGE | TC_CMR_CPCTRG;
  REG_TC0_BMR   = TC_BMR_QDEN | TC_BMR_SPEEDEN /*| TC_BMR_EDGPHA*/;
  REG_TC0_CCR0  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC0_CCR1  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC0_CCR2  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;

  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC25B_TIOA6, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 5
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC26B_TIOB6, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 4

  REG_TC2_CMR2  = TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4 | TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_ACPC_TOGGLE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC;
  REG_TC2_RC2   = F_CPU / 128 / 10;
  REG_TC2_CMR0  = TC_CMR_ABETRG | TC_CMR_LDRA_EDGE | TC_CMR_LDRB_EDGE | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_EDGE | TC_CMR_CPCTRG;
  REG_TC2_BMR   = TC_BMR_QDEN | TC_BMR_POSEN /*| TC_BMR_EDGPHA*/;
  REG_TC2_CCR0  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC2_CCR1  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC2_CCR2  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
```

Comment: I am using Arduino IDE for programming. According to **Quadrature Decoder QDEC for SAM3/4 Devices_ApplicationNote_AT11483** Pg 16 I have to first configure the IOpins. How can i configure TIOA6 and TIOB6 as QDEC input pins?

Comment: @KIVV Please see the above comment

Comment: @MasoodSalik How exactly it's done right now for TC0? Some library or directly in arduino? Do you have code for it? And also which Arduino IDE - there is arduino.cc and arduino.org

Comment: I have posted the code in another post   http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/how-to-configure-2nd-quadrature-decoder-io-pins-in-arduino-ide

Comment: I am currently using Arduino IDE 1.6.10.(zip file download fromhttps://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) After Installing the board "Arduino SAM board (32 bit ARM Cortex M3). All libraries of DUE are already added in it.